# Error: Conversion of one or more geometries failed. Please check whether input is valid. Invalid argument

Tags: android, arcgis, esri, coordinate-systems, esri-arc-engine

I'm trying to convert a Point to anything else but every function i use gives me the same error:

**Error: Conversion of one or more geometries failed. Please check whether input is valid. Invalid argument**

```
 Point identifyPoint = mapview.toMapPoint(e.getX(), e.getY());
 String s = CoordinateConversion.pointToDecimalDegrees(identifyPoint, mapview.getSpatialReference(), 2);
```

This is the code i'm using, What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

What is the current spatialreference of the mapview?

Please ensure that mapview.getSpatialReference() is not returning null. that could also cause problem.

Comment: It's not null. I played with the SPs and created some to test with.
Basically the one i receive back from mapview is 102100.
And the only one that doesn't give me an error is 4326.

But it also gives me the wrong coordinates.(90N)

Btw, not sure how it can be null at all.
I can't set it in any way(the SP of the mapview).


Also, adding graphics work just fine, it's only when i try to convert the point that i receive this error.

Comment: Could you share the getX and getY values as well as the identifyPoint x and y values.

Comment: MotionEvent:
X = 641.4380493164063
Y = 197.2734375

Point:
X = 4.3910381484061874E7
Y = 3874080.1824269504

Comment: Something else seem to be wrong here. You see the point X value is greater than the bounds of the projection system. Which location are you trying to click(place name).

Comment: Just random location.
It's like that with every location.
I'm using the map from ESRI webservice.